# Chrome Incognito mode broken in latest version?

Tags: google-chrome, search, private-browsing

I've used Chrome's incognito mode for sensitive searches where some of our company's competitive information is involved so that when I use my laptop at other meetings etc. the autocomplete bar does not accidentally reveal a like or search that might give other companies a clue about some of our confidential projects.

Worked fine so far. But just yesterday I had some links start to show up in my normal Chrome Window that I am pretty sure I never searched or accessed in anything other than an incognito window.

To verify, I even went to my search history and searched on those links and they are indeed present in the history and all searched in the last 1-2 days.

It could be a coincidence, but I had simultanously noticed that Chrome's incognito tab looks have changed the last 1-2 days. i.e. It now opens with a dark background? See screenshot below.

Is this some new bug? Or am I doing some setting wrong that may have accidentally changed in an automatic upgrade of Chrome.

PS. Has Google also changed some fonts / icons etc. in the recent auto-updates to Chrome. e.g. The font in the address bar looks different to me and even the i favicon next to the address. (see screenshot below). Just making sure these are changes others are seeing too.

[image]

### **A regular tab's look vs the new look of an incognito window**

[image]

[image]

### New fonts and icons

[image]

Comment: I tend to use a whole different browser and still put it in "private browsing" or it's local equivalent of incognito mode for this sort of thing, to maintain complete separation from my "normal" browser. In your case that might mean branching out to a different browser (I don't find it a big deal, some folks do.) Naturally, stay signed out of any cloud connections as well.

Comment: @Ecnerwal No cloud connections for me. I used to do the different browser thing too a few years ago (IE + Chrome). But for the last 2-3 years Chrome's incognito mode worked so well that I didn't bother. It only broke this last few days. Or I'm doing something wrong.